I'm facing an issue with material-tailwind Carousel component
I try to add material-tailwind/react **Carousel ** component to my Applayout.tsx but I'm facing with an issue
" Type '{ children: Element[]; className: string; placeholder: undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<CarouselProps, "children" | "color" | "transition" | "translate" | "slot" | "style" | "title" | "onChange" | "loop" | "onClick" | "className" | "key" | "defaultChecked" | ... 252 more ... | "slideRef">': onPointerEnterCapture, onPointerLeaveCapture "
import React from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { Header } from "../pages/Header";
import {
  Carousel
} from "@material-tailwind/react";

const AppLayout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
      <Carousel className="rounded-xl"> //issue here
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497436072909-60f360e1d4b1?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2560&q=80"
          alt="image 1"
          className="h-full w-full object-cover"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493246507139-91e8fad9978e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2940&q=80"
          alt="image 2"
          className="h-full w-full object-cover"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518623489648-a173ef7824f3?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2762&q=80"
          alt="image 3"
          className="h-full w-full object-cover"
        />
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
};

export { AppLayout };

I also config @material-tailwind/react, here you guys can see.
const withMT = require("@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT");

module.exports = withMT({
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./**/@material-tailwind/**/*.{html,js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
});

Problem with Carousel and others at @material-tailwind/react


What is your @types/react version?
I downgraded to "@types/react": "18.2.42" and it worked.
"@types/react": "18.2.42" is the last working version. It seems the problem was introduced when this was merged DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#67170
